# Object masking/ dynamic hiding in render is not exporting to .glb

Tags: animation, export, masking, gltf

I'm new to GLB export. I am using a series of models generated in a structure deformation calculation code as .ply files, that I import in my scene. Each model represents the studied structure at a different stage of deformation.
What I would like to do is to export an animation showing them one after each other in a .glb file.

I tried it with a mask modifier on each of the models and tuning them all so that only one model is visible at a time, but it does not work. The GLB file even has no animation at all.

I also tried to toggle the renderability on and off with keyframes, while ticking the "limit to renderable objects" option. But the result is the same.

I am aware that I should use identically named NLA tracks for the export to include several animations on different objects. This was the case in the attempts I described. I checked that I was able to export the models moving, but the visibility in the GLB file is the property I can't find how to animate. It seems to just be ignored when exporting.

Any ideas or suggestions as to what I could change would help me a lot !
Thanks :)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Thanks a lot for this one ! I didn't come across it. So if I understand well this is doomed... Even though I have no business with shaders and all I want is geometry, the problem is that the dynamic hiding is blender-specific.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an animation on the scale of the models. They're all set to zero scale except for the time I want them to appear, with keyframe interpolation set to "constant". This animation works in the .glb with the same result as if dynamic hiding were possible.